# CppDepend plugin crashing visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cppdepend

I'm having trouble starting visual studio ( 2012 and 2013 ) after installing the CppDepend plugin.

Some info windows provides that might help:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 12.0.31101.0
  Problem Signature 03: 54548724
  Problem Signature 04: CppDepend.AddIn
  Problem Signature 05: 5.0.0.622
  Problem Signature 06: 5493421d
  Problem Signature 07: ca
  Problem Signature 08: e
  Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.27
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: dac6
  Additional Information 4: dac6c2650fa14dd558bd9f448e23afd1
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Could you please send a full stack trace to support@cppdepend.com

Comment: @JamesfromCppDependTeam sent